# Auto opening iOS app/wallet when in close proximity

Tags: ios, nfc, wallet

Hey I’m just getting into iOS dev so I’m still not 100% on the features yet. I wanted to play around with making a ticketing app and wanted to make a system similar to the workflow of how Apple Pay works with NFC to auto-open the wallet app.

Is it possible in any way to either integrate a custom wallet card that’s activated by NFC (or other tech) or to automatically open my app on close proximity?

Cheers.

Comment: Yes it’s possible to add a pass.  You’ll need to apply to Apple for a NFC certificate.  However the bigger challenge will be reading these passes.  You’ll need a terminal enabled for the Apple VAS protocol, and configured with your pass details.

Comment: thanks for that, feel free to make this the answer and I'll give it to you, it seems that nobody else had much to say!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it’s possible to add a pass that will automatically display via NFC, but you’ll need to apply to Apple for a NFC certificate and add an [NFC dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-DontLinkElementID_3) to `pass.json`.

However the bigger challenge will be reading these passes. You’ll need a terminal enabled for the Apple VAS protocol, and configured with your pass details.

Here's a [video](https://vimeo.com/232958629) of something similar in action between an Apple Wallet pass and an Android powered POS handset.

Comment: Is NFC certificate required development too? If so, is it possible for individual developer to get that certificate from Apple?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is also required for development.  I would recommend that you contact your local Apple Developer Relations team directly or your regional Apple Pay team.